# Second return type in function declaration?

Tags: c, mplab

I ran across the following function declaration while looking at some generated C code from MPLabX's Code Configurator.

```
void __interrupt() INTERRUPT_InterruptManager(void) {
...
}
```

What is the `__interrupt()` part of that declaration? I don't think it's a second return type, so what is it?

In response to a couple comments, what is this type of declaration called (if it is something that can be done in general, instead of just in MPLab)? Is it a function attribute?

Comment: It is a compiler extension to mark the function as interrupt handler, so it will know it should generate some special code for it matching the interrupts convention on the specific target.

Comment: This function is an IRQ Interrupt. which means it interrupts the runnig thread and gets executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The compiler extends the C/C++ language by adding the __interrupt
>   keyword, which specifies that a function is treated as an interrupt
>   function. This keyword is an IRQ interrupt. The alternate keyword,
>   "interrupt", may also be used except in strict ANSI C or C++ modes.

For more information: [__interrupt](http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRUI04/the---interrupt-keyword-stdz0559860.html)

Comment: Okay, so it's a compiler extension, not something that can be done in general in C. Thanks!